# Should I install xampp or wamp?

Tags: php, iis, xampp, wamp

So I have IIS manager already installed in my computer, 
and I want to update to php7 then install laravel, but the video tutorials, articles and documentations online is mostly geared towards people who use xampp and wamp I couldn't find a tutorial for IIS. I really want to download and install xampp or wamp, but our professor said to us"to dont ever install xampp or wamp in our computer, something bad will happen to the computer and it will just complicates everything". so I am stuck, what should I do?

Comment: Aha like what he said, well its entirely up to you which one you want to use really. I used wampp and IIS but you can't use them in parallel, its easy to install php on IIS. "nothing bad will happen to your computer" don't believe your professor he's lying! aha.

Comment: @MrNew Of course you can use IIS and Apache in parallel... people do that all the time.  Just use different ports.  You can even proxy one to the other.

Comment: yeah missing part "not" with the same ports.

Comment: While compare XAMPP & WAMP, WAMP will win. You can change PHP,MySQL and even Apache versions if you're developing projects in different versions in WAMP. XAMPP will be a headache for you. If you're running IIS , you may use it for running PHP projects and there is no need to install any other applications for running PHP projects.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

> but our professor said to us"to dont ever install xampp or wamp in our computer, something bad will happen to the computer and it will just complicates everything"
>
> so I am stuck, what should I do?

For starters, find a new professor.  Anyone that tells you to do something with such absolute statements and without explanation has no business trying to teach.

There are plenty of reasons WAMP and such aren't all that useful, but they certainly won't cause something bad to happen to your computer.

Apache HTTPD is a web server that's been used for an eternity, but we have better alternatives.  Nginx for example is typically much more efficient due to its threading model.

MySQL is a database server that's also been in use for a long time, but PostgreSQL has surpassed it in capability, and it's also available under an open source license.  Particularly, it's JSON-B types allow for a document model inside of a record, with complete query support.  Pretty amazing stuff, and comes in handy.

PHP... well that's a valid option if you want to use PHP, and it sounds like you do.

> So I have IIS manager already installed in my computer, and I want to update to php7

There's actually an installer available that does everything for you.  Really, you should be choosing a web server based on its functionality and efficiency, not based on how hard it is to install PHP.  In any case, since you already have IIS, there's no reason you can't use it.  IIS works just fine with PHP.

> then install laravel

You might have to set up some rewrite rules differently than your tutorials say, but otherwise it shouldn't matter so much what web server you're using.  If you want to use IIS, it would be a good exercise for you to learn how to set up this sort of project.

> video tutorials, articles and documentations online is mostly geared towards people who use xampp and wamp

Don't follow tutorials step-by-step, learn what they're having you do.  Then, learn how to do those things in the setup you want.

> what should I do?

If it were me, I'd set up a VM with Vagrant, and use a repeatable configurable setup process which is scripted, so you can then repeat it exactly on production servers.  Having a VM also gives you a convenient snapshot that you can roll back to as you configure your system and make mistakes.  (You should still be using version control for your code.)

Comment: _There are plenty of reasons WAMP and such aren't all that useful_ I would love to see a list of them.

Comment: @RiggsFolly For starters, Nginx is superior to Apache HTTPD, both in capability and in performance.  There's no reason to build new applications on Apache.  Next, Postgres is much more capable than MySQL.  The only benefit I see in MySQL is the ability to change your storage engine per-table, but this is rarely needed.  PHP has come along ways, and is fine... but you might consider Hacklang as a performant typed alternative.  As for Windows, there's nothing wrong with Windows but you should be developing/testing in the target environment.  Are you paying for Windows licenses on servers?

Comment: @RiggsFolly Most people are installing WAMP as a development environment.  We have better alternatives now.  As I said in my post, look into a Vagrant-managed VM, with Nginx and Postgres.  It's easier to set up than WAMP and allows you to easily have several projects at once without conflicting.

Comment: @Brad you are the one who's complicating everything

Comment: @NorielleCruz How's that?  Anything I can explain for you?  While you're busy manually setting up a config and hoping its repeatable, I just run `vagrant init` and `vagrant up`, knowing that I've set up a consistent development server that is pretty close to what I'll have in production.

Answer (score 0):

**If required you can install but need to make sure few things please check below the whole case:**

I am facing this problem I have Xampp and WAMP both in separate drive and XAMPP work with its default port 80 for PHP and 3306 for MySQL. So I configured the Wampp of a separate directory and different PHP and MySQL versions.

I also change the default port from 80 to 8080 and 3306 to 3307 for WAMP and now I am able to access the PHPMyAdmin but not able to access the project with an older version i.e PHP 5.6

When trying to access the project folder on localhost:8080/project_name it threw me the error i.e "**No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.**"

**STEPS:**
**1)** Xampp was already installed so I did not make any changes over there keep the default port 80 for apache and 3306 for the MySQL
So your localhost will work something like this
http://localhost/
http://localhost/phpmyadmin/index.php

**2)** And I change the default post in WAMP that is 80 to 8080 for apache and MySQL default port from 3306 to 3307 for MYSAL
http://localhost:8080/
http://localhost:8080/phpmyadmin/index.php

**3)** How does the MySQL Connectivity you need to do in this case

```
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost:3307');
define('DB_USER', 'root');
define('DB_PASSWORD', '');    
define('DB_DATABASE', 'databasename');
$connection=mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD) or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db(DB_DATABASE,$connection);
```